# Rotating an entire canvas by 90 degree in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have drawn an image with CustomPainter (foregroundPainter) in flutter. In some screens I want to rotate the image, the entire canvas, by 90 degree. Is it possible? Can somebody show me some piece of code?

Thanks

Sudheer

Answer (score 1):

Try with `RotatedBox` widget.

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: Text("Your widget")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can use **Transform.rotate** to rotate your widget.

Rotated it with 90˚ (π/2)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Transform.rotate(angle: math.pi / 2, child: Text("Text"),);
}
```

Option 2: If you want to rotate something 90, 180, or 270 degrees, You can use RotatedBox

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: new Text("My Text")
)
```